# Can't find the message author

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

In this line of code I am trying to send private message, to initial message author. For some unknown reason there is an error:

> (node:17560) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Here is this line of code:

```
const appStart = await message.author.send(questions[collectCounter++]);
```

Here is whole file:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const {Client, Message, MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
    name: 'apply',
    /**
     * 
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {Messafe} message 
     * @param {String[]} args 
     */
    run : async(client, message, args) => {
        const questions = [
            "What is your in-game name?",
            "Do you accept the rules?",
            "How old are you?",
            "Where are you from?",
            "How long have you been playing Minecraft?",
            "Where did you find the server?",
            "Have you ever been banned from another server on Minecraft? If yes, what was the reason?",
            "Why should we accept you?",
        ]
        let collectCounter = 0;
        let endCounter = 0;
        
        const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
        
        const appStart = await message.author.send(questions[collectCounter++]);        
        const channel = appStart.channel;
        
        const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter);
        
        collector.on("collect", () => {
            if(collectCounter < questions.length) {
                channel.send(questions[collectedCounter++]);
            } else {
                channel.send("Your application has been sent!");
                collector.stop("fulfilled");
            }
        });

        const appsChannel = client.channel.cache.get('863534867668009004');
        collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
            if(reason === 'fulfilled') {
                let index = 1;
                const mappedResponses = collected.map((msg) => {
                    return `&{index++}) &{questions[endCounter++]}\n-> ${msg.content}`
                })
                .join('\n\n');
            }

            appsChannel.send(message.channel.send('New Application!', mappedResponses));
        });
    },
};
```

This is my index.js:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

const BOT_ID = "863550035923697674";

const prefix = "!";

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setActivity("ur cheat files...", {
    type: "WATCHING",
    url: "https://discord.gg/bzYXx8t3fE"
  });
});

for(const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on("message", message => {
  let userID = message.author.id;
  if (userID == BOT_ID) {
    return;
  }
  const version = "Wersja bota 0.2";
  ///const args = message.content;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  if(!client.commands.has(command)) return;
  try{
      client.commands.get(command).run(message, args);
  }catch(error){
      console.error(error);
      message.reply('**There was an issue executing that command!**');
  }
});

client.login("tokenishere");
```

**Thanks for help!**

Comment: Did you try logging the message object before the line it throws the error?

Answer (score 3):

This just means that `message` is not what you think it is. In your command handler, you executed the command with the arguments `message` and `args` (order matters). However, in the command file, you expected the parameters to be `client`, `message`, and then `args`.

This means, that in your command file, `client` actually refers to the message, `message` actually refers to the args, and the third parameter doesn't exist.

To fix this problem, you can modify the names and order of the parameters in either file.

Comment: Yeah also you should change `Messafe` to `Message`… (in your jsdoc)

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy fix... as @Lioness100 mentioned your parameters are wrong and im here to show a code example

locate this line of code in `index.js` :

```
client.commands.get(command).run(message, args);
// and change it to
client.commands.get(command).run(message, args, client);
```

after wards go to your "File" and fine this line of code :

```
run : async(client, message, args) => {
// And change it to
run : async(message, args) => {
```

**Your problem** was that you were executing wrong parameters in Your "File" so you just needed to change your parameters from `client, message, args` to `message, args, client`

This is a common mistake

Comment: I personally recommend not even adding `client` as a parameter and just sticking with `message` and `args`. This is because you can always access the client through `message.client` anyways.

Comment: I agree on that @Lioness100

Comment: Well I did what you reccomended, but than I got error in line 41 
`const appsChannel = client.channel.cache.get('863534867668009004');`

that says: 
`(node:32096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: client is not defined`


So basically now it can't recognise client(maybe)

Comment: Ok then just replace the parameters to `message, args, client`

Comment: Ok then just replace the parameters to message, args, client @SzymonRudnikowski this should fix the error have a good day